# Messenger Send API + AWS S3 hosted object

Tags: node.js, facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, facebook-messenger

I have an png uploaded to an S3 bucket with public read permissions. When I use the Messenger API to send it, I get the following error:

`Messenger Error received. For more information about error codes, see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/error-codes
{ message: '(#100) Failed to fetch the file from the url',
  type: 'OAuthException',
  code: 100,
  error_subcode: 2018008,
  fbtrace_id: 'F8w/11MzB9B' }`

My S3 url is in the format https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/filename.png, and when I visit it, it works BUT results in auto-download. Does Messenger expect a displayed image? If so how might I change the S3 settings to permit this.

Thanks all!

Comment: To fix the image display in a browser, set the `content-type` metadata on the object to the correct mime type. I doubt that's the issue with Facebook though, but it's worth fixing as a first debugging step. Have you enabled static website hosting and enabled CORS on the bucket?

Comment: @MarkB I did set the `content-type`, what do you mean by static website hosting / enabled CORS? (I enabled PUT/POST so I could putobject)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Messenger doesn't accept png file types, despite me seeing examples of png's being sent in the documentation :(.

Sending a jpeg instead works.

Making sure that the S3 object was uploaded with a `Content-Type` specified and public read permissions (or pre-signed URL) is important.

EDIT: works but doesn't work with pre-signed requests

Comment: Pretty sure that’s not true. More likely that you did not manage to set the _correct_ Content-Type for PNG perhaps …?

Comment: @CBroe perhaps! I'm sticking with JPEG for now though ... however, I can't seem to get it to work with pre-signed URLs, any ideas?